# $\mathcal{B}$ an algebra $\implies f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}) $ an algebra

Tags: measure-theory, inverse-function, algebras

Im trying to prove the following statement:

Let $f: \Omega \to E$.

$\mathcal{B}$ an algebra on $E$ $\implies f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}) $ an algebra on $\Omega$.

To show that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B})$ is an algebra, following has to hold:

1. $\Omega \in f^{-1}(\mathcal{B})$
2. Stable under complementation
3. Stable under finite union

My question:

In the first point, since $\mathcal{B}$ is an algebra on $E$, it follows that $E \in \mathcal{B}$. But how do I even know if $f^{-1}(E)$ is defined? Don't we need the restriction that the function needs to be bijective in order to gurantee that $f^{-1}$ is possible?

**EDIT (after suggestion by Henno Brandsma)**

1. $\Omega \in f^{-1}(\mathcal{B})$ since $f^{-1}[E] = \Omega$.And $E \in \mathcal{B}$
2. Then regarding the complement: I take any $A \in \mathcal{B}$ so the complement would be $A^c = E \setminus A$. Note that $A^c \in \mathcal{B}$. So $f^{-1}[E\setminus A]= \Omega \setminus f^{-1}[A]$ and $f^{-1}[A]$ is defined since we know $f^{-1}[E] = \Omega$ and $A \subset E$. So we have the complement of $f^{-1}[A]$ as well.
3. This one follows from the fact that $f^{-1}[\bigcup_i A_i] = \bigcup_i f^{-1}[A_i]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that

- $f^{-1}[E]=\Omega$
- $f^{-1}[E\setminus A] = \Omega\setminus f^{-1}[A]$ for all $A \subseteq E$,
- $f^{-1}[\bigcup_i A_i] = \bigcup_i f^{-1}[A_i]$

Note that $f^{-1}[A]$ is **always** defined, it's just the set $$\{x \in \Omega\mid f(x) \in A\}$$

Comment: I've made an edit after considering your points. Is it right that we have to assume $f^{-1}[E] = \Omega$ and is the third point of yours always true?

Comment: @MyGanton You don't have to assume $f^{-1}[E] = \Omega$, this holds by definition! And the last is true for all unions, finite and infinite, and all $A_i \subseteq E$, yes. You should have learnt that in your first set theory class.

Comment: I don't see why $f^{-1}[E] = \Omega$. How do I know that $f(\Omega)$ maps to the whole space $E$?

Comment: @MyGanton $x \in f^{-1}[E]$ if $f(x) \in E$ and this is always the case for any $x \in \Omega$ because $f$ is **defined** to be a function from $\Omega$ to $E$, which means that every $x$ in $\Omega$ has some unique image in $E$. $f[\Omega] =E$ is a different thing, as $f[A]$ is not defined the same way.

Comment: I realised where I got confused, thank you very much!

Comment: @MyGanton Glad I could help..